# Java - error when creating arraylist

Tags: java

So I am a beginner to java (not to programming), and I encoutered a problem where it wont let me create an arrayList:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
public class OrderingNumbers{
    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>(); //<--this one does not work
    ArrayList sortedNumbers = new ArrayList();//<-- This one works
    while(keepRunning){
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you want to sort the numbers or add a number?");
        String answer = input.readLine();
        if(answer.equals("sort")){
           for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(numbers.get(i));

           }
           System.out.println("Bye Bye.");
           keepRunning = false;
        }else if(answer.equals("add")){
            System.out.print("What number to you want to add?");
            numbers.add(input.readLine());
            System.out.println("Added number.");
        }else{
            System.out.print("That is not an option.");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried doing this as well, `ArrayList<String> strArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();`  but still does not work.  I am trying to allow the user to add another number to the array if they want.

Comment: Don't use raw types. How does it not work?

Comment: Which version of java are you compiling against?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It says it is an invalid assigment operator

Comment: @Jack How would I find that?

Comment: Go to your console / terminal and type: `java -version`

Comment: So you get a clear an concise compiler error but for some reason you don't think that is relevant information to put in the question?

Comment: @Jack 1.8.0_121

Comment: Set the language level in your IDE appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class OrderingNumbers{
    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    // here is the corrected line
    List numbers = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList sortedNumbers = new ArrayList();//<-- This one works
    // add data to sort
    numbers.add(0, 1);  // adds 1 at 0 index
    numbers.add(1, 2);  // adds 2 at 1 index
    System.out.println(numbers);
    while(keepRunning){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you want to sort the numbers or add a number?");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("sort")){
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(numbers.get(i));
            // note does not actually do any sorting

           }
           System.out.println("Bye Bye.");
           keepRunning = false;
        }else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){
            System.out.print("What number to you want to add?");
            numbers.add(input.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Added number.");
        }else{
            System.out.print("That is not an option.");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: DataInputStream readLine has been depreciated. I changed it to Scanner Class to get rid of that warning.

Comment: Also use equalsIgnoreCase instead of equals on the  if's. this allows SORT or Sort or sort

Comment: Explanations belong into the post, not hidden in the comment section.

Comment: Never figured out how to add normal text then code then normal text again. hence the reason for expains in the comments

Comment: Just write your text and then your code (with leading four spaces, like you have right now). Just make sure that there is at least one empty line between text and code (or the code won't be rendered in a code block).

Answer (score 0):

The normal usage is as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

So typically:

- Most general type (List) for variables so implementation may be changed later, and all kind of Lists will fit.
- Always typed `List<...>`.
- Using the diamond `<>` operator.

The error might have been an `import java.awt.List;` which is an other class with the same name. Probably not here.

To sort (integer) numbers a `List<Integer>` would seem more logic, as 9 < 10, but "9" greater than "10" alphabetically.

For reading text better use Scanner as mentioned in an other answer. It has:

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    numbers.add(number); // adds an Integer with number's value.
...
```

The real error is unclear however.

Comment: Do you guys not grab the code posted and compile it? he was getting a depreciation error

Comment: @JeremiahStillings I got just some red ears, To the OP: deprecated means still allowable but bad style, and maybe no longer compilable in the future. I leave the answer as it is for the proposed changes.

Comment: @JeremiahStillings Using deprecated code ___is not an error___. It is inappropriate, yes, but not an error.

Comment: did not  mean to offend you. it was a  real question. Do you all not really run the code? how do you tell what error the users are getting since 99 percent of the questions are just a snipet of code with no errors posted or no  clear question

Comment: @JeremiahStillings *"Do you all not really run the code?"* - I did and OPs code is working fine when using the proper language level. *"how do you tell what error the users are getting"* - By reading what he wrote ... *"`List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>(); //<--this one does not work`"*. That's not related to the input style (which isn't an error anyway) and the only reason that this fails is: wrong language level (since OP already uses Java 8).

Comment: Thanks Tom. I do not understand what you mean by wrong language level , but that is ok. I think the OP got what he needed.

Comment: @JeremiahStillings Yes you have to differ "language level" (or compliance level) and installed Java version. Even if you have Java 8 installed, you can set it up to work like Java 5 (or any other older version). Some IDEs have a default language level of Java 5 (for no sane reason :/) and that doesn't support generics. (If you already know that, then just ignore this comment :D)